# overriding get_fields in ModelAdmin return this fiels on all model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to add languages related fields to ModelAdmin, for save as json after.

But these fields appear in all the models of my applications. Why?

For example with a simple app:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel2(models.Model):
    txt_field = models.TextField()

class TestModel(models.Model):
    txt_field = models.TextField()
```

admin.py:

```
from moduleadmin.models import TestModel, TestModel2
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms

class TestModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        my_fields = super(TestModelAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        new_fields = [(lang[0], forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=(lang[0] == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE))
            ) for lang in settings.LANGUAGES]
        for f in new_fields:
            if f[0] not in my_fields:
                my_fields.append(f[0])
            self.form.declared_fields.update({f[0]: f[1]})
        return my_fields

admin.site.register(TestModel, TestModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(TestModel2)
```

and in settings.py I've added:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', 'French'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)
```

So if I try to add one  TestModel2 entry, It's ok.
But if i go to TestModel add entry form, and return to TestModel2 add, I've the two fields appear in forms.

Can you help me? Or maybe there's a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you want to have fields based on the languages you have. If that's the case you'd better look at some 3rd party library like [django-modeltranslation](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/])